# Curl: can't save cookies in cookiejar

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm trying to login to kiala website. Kiala is a "shipping" compagny and I like to get a new shipping token with php. Since there is no api for doing this I tried with curl. Now I don't have much experience with curl and I can't make curl saving the cookies to the jar. I've tried many things but now I get to the point that I want to rip my hair off. I need these cookies to make further requests.

I've made a dummy account for testing

> **website:** http://www.kialaverzendservice.be/
>
> **login form:** http://www.kialaverzendservice.be/login.required.action?os_destination=%2Fsender%2Fstart.action
>
> **email:** kialatest@mailinator.com
>
> **pwd:** test123

I get the following header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 10 Oct 2013 09:46:37 GMT Server:
Apache-Coyote/1.1 Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-15 Vary:
Accept-Encoding Set-Cookie:
berkano-seraph-login=eGV5ZcKEZXhlwoZlwoJkfGJ5Y31jemTCgGJ7YsKGYsKCYnhifmLCgmLChmN6YsKGY3dmwoNiwoZjwoNjeGh+YnhjfWJ5Yn1mwoFmwoFm;
Expires=Fri, 10-Oct-2014 09:46:37 GMT; Path=/ Set-Cookie:
kiala-c2c-language=nl; Expires=Tue, 28-Oct-2081 13:00:44 GMT; Path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

My simplified php code: I'm able to login but the cookies in the header are not set in my cookiejar-file? btw I'm on localhost (wamp), but I don't think it matters.

```
loginToKiala();


function loginToKiala(){


            $url = 'http://kialaverzendservice.be/sender/start.action';

            //POST vars
            $fields = array(
                                    'os_username' => urlencode('kialatest@mailinator.com'),
                                    'os_password' => urlencode('test123'),
                                    'os_cookie'=>urlencode('true')//remember me
                            );

            //url-ify the data for the POST
            $fields_string='';
            foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
            rtrim($fields_string, '&');

            $ch=curl_init();

            $cookie_file = './cookies.txt';

            if (! file_exists($cookie_file) || ! is_writable($cookie_file))
            {
                echo 'Cookie file missing or not writable.';
                exit;
            }
            //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);


            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
            //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.kialaverzendservice.be/');//set referer for first request
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);




            curl_exec ($ch); // execute the curl command

            curl_close ($ch);
            unset($ch);

        }
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're not using `CURLOPT_POST` correctly. cURL is expecting `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `1` or `0`. The function you have there, `count($fields)` will (probably) return a number higher than one.

Do this instead:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
```

At least, if I understand correctly that you want to use POST instead of GET.